# Grails not rendering alternate views

Tags: grails

Is anyone else having problems getting **grails 3.2** to render alternate views?     I can’t even get a simple example to work. No stack trace either. Just won’t render the view. I am using the web profile.

```
def one(){
  render( view:'two')
}

def two(){
}
```

Comment: what is shown in the browser? 404? Do you even have that `two.gsp` page created?

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone else having problems getting grails 3.2 to render
>   alternate views.

I am not.

See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/alternateview

https://github.com/jeffbrown/alternateview/blob/b5560f627eee03d19ff6a0b4ff9e3093800e4d05/grails-app/controllers/demo/DemoController.groovy

```
package demo

class DemoController {
    def one(){
        render( view:'two')
    }

    def two(){
    }
}
```

Both of those appear to work.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to put this example together Jeff. It looks like my problem was that I did not have <html> or a <body> tag in my two.gsp file. I was able to get away with this in grails 2 but it looks like this is not the case in grails 3.

Comment: @JeffT I think that only accidentally worked and we never documented as intended behavior.  GSP templates should be fragments but GSP pages are supposed to be complete with html and body tags.